# how to reset taxonomy term ids after deleting all term from all vocabularies

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

after deleting all terms from all vocabularies we are still left with the next available ID of last created term

is there any module that does such a thing ?
or one has to go manually and set the auto increment ?
are there are any side effects with using manual way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up phpmyadmin and do a query

```
ALTER TABLE `taxonomy_term_data` auto_increment = 1
```

or using drush

```
drush sql-query "ALTER TABLE taxonomy_term_data auto_increment = 1"
```

But not sure that this is recommended.

NOTE: I am assuming that all terms have been deleted from within the UI